# tkinter.ttk.Treeview root node icon/image does not appear

Tags: image, python-3.x, treeview, python-imaging-library, ttk

**Problem:** I am not able to get an icon image to appear next to the root node in tkinter.ttk.Treeview. Below is a test code I used. It executed w/o errors but image did not appear on the left of root node. I have tried using the full path name of the image file but that did not work. Also, I have tried using PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage to open the image file but that did not work either. Instead an error as shown below appeared.

**Question:** How do I get an icon image to appear on the left of the root node (or any node) of tkinter.ttk.Treeview?

**Test Code:**

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, path):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
    ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
    xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Directory', anchor='w')

    abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
    i = './icon/Home-icon_16.gif'
    root_pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=i)
    #root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
    root_node = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=abspath, open=True, image=root_pic)
    l1_node = self.tree.insert(root_node, 'end', text='level 1', open=True)
    l2_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2', open=True)
    l3_node = self.tree.insert(l2_node, 'end', text='level 3', open=True)
    l2a_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2a', open=True)
    l3a_node = self.tree.insert(l2a_node, 'end', text='level 3a', open=True)

    self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    self.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
path_to_my_project = os.getcwd()
app = App(root, path=path_to_my_project)
app.mainloop()
```

**Error msg from using PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage:**

```
root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 296, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageMode.py", line 52, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: './icon/Home-icon_16.gif'
```

**Home-icon_16.gif**:
[image: Home-icon_16.gif]

**Applications:** python3.5 ver3.5.1-10; python3-tk ver3.5.1-1; tk8.6 ver8.6.5-1; python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 ver3.1.2-0ubuntu1

Comment: The error you post doesn't match the code. The error shows the statement `root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)`, but the code shows `root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=i)`.

Comment: Bryan, the error does match my code. The error occurs when I uncomment #root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i) and comment root_pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=i). As I mentioned in my problem statement, I tried two approaches. The root_pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=i) executed w/o error. But the root_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i) approach showed the error I reported above. I learned from Stevo's answer below that what is missing is the use of "self." before the instance name of the image. By doing so, it creates a reference to the image and I think overcomes a tk bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating PIL image first with `Image.open('file_path')` and then do `Photoimage`. Also, you need to keep a reference to the PhotoImage or it wont show in tkinter.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, path):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Directory', anchor='w')

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        i = './icon/Home-icon_16.gif'
        root_pic1 = Image.open(i)                           # Open the image like this first
        self.root_pic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(root_pic1)      # Then with PhotoImage. NOTE: self.root_pic2 =     and not     root_pic2 =

        root_node = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=abspath, open=True, image=self.root_pic2)
        l1_node = self.tree.insert(root_node, 'end', text='level 1', open=True)
        l2_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2', open=True)
        l3_node = self.tree.insert(l2_node, 'end', text='level 3', open=True)
        l2a_node = self.tree.insert(l1_node, 'end', text='level 2a', open=True)
        l3a_node = self.tree.insert(l2a_node, 'end', text='level 3a', open=True)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
path_to_my_project = os.getcwd()
app = App(root, path=path_to_my_project)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Stevo. So simply putting a "self." before image instance name i.e. "self.root_pic1" will work. Problem. The home image has appeared but it has not replace the default arrow symbol used to toggle the open and close status of the node. Why is this so? I had assumed using the image keyword in the .insert() method will replace the default arrows. Can you tell he how to achieve this?

Comment: Stevo, I think it is more appropriate to post my question as a new question given that it is a different question.