# How to add pictures to a Tkinter Treeview as values?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

How can I add picture to ttk `Treeview`? Example Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
okno = Tk()

def maketable():
    style = ttk.Style(okno)
    style.configure("TVS.Treeview", rowheight=40)
    tv = Treeview(okno, style="TVS.Treeview")

    tv['columns'] = ('LName', 'Pic')
    tv.heading("#0", text='Jméno', anchor='w')
    tv.column("#0", anchor="w", width=200)

    tv.heading('LName', text='Příjmení')
    tv.column('LName', anchor='center', width=200)

    tv.heading('Pic', text='Obrazek')
    tv.column('Pic', anchor='center', width=200)

    dbf = open("xxx.json", 'r')
    db = json.loads(dbf.read())
for i in range(0, len(db)):
    root_pic1 = Image.open(db[i]["Pic"])
    root_pic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(root_pic1) 
    tv.insert('', 'end', image=root_pic2, text=db[i]['Name'], values=(db[i]['LName'])) 


tv.pack()


def main():
    okno.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    maketable()
    main()
```

I want the "Pic" Column to have pictures - this means a picture shouldn't be in `#0` because it is a value. In `db[i]["Pic"]` there is a file path. In the `values=()` I can't add images—it doesn't show anything.

EDIT: Thanks for solution but doesnt work on multiple images:

```
for i in range(0, len(db)):
    tv._image = Image
    tv._image = Image.open(db[i]["Pic"])
    tv._image.thumbnail((100, 200), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tv._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tv._image)
    tv.insert('', 'end', image=tv._image, values=(db[i]['Name'], db[i]['LName'])) 


tv.pack()
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549976/tkinter-ttk-treeview-root-node-icon-image-does-not-appear) may help.

Comment: I don't see any code which load image. Show it. If you use PIL/Pillow then read note about problem with Pillow and Garbage Collector on page http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: @Nae tried, nothing happend

Comment: @furas edited code with Nae suggestion.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the PhotoImage or it wont show.

Comment: @StevoMitricwhat? How can I do that... Sorry I am begginner

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman it seems you didn't read about problem with "Garbage Collector" - link added by Nae show the same problem - image assigned to local variable is removed from memory and Tkitner can't display it.

Comment: at start you can use `global root_pic2` in `maketable` and image will be assigned to global variable and Python doesn't remove it from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Nae and @furas pointed out, local variables are removed when function finishes and your images get garbage collected.

you would need to do something like:

```
tv._image = Image.open('test.png')
tv._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tv._image)

for i in range(0, len(db)):

    tv.insert('', 'end', image=tv._image, text=db[i]['Name'], values=(db[i]['LName']))
```

or define them outside the function. It would be ideal if you were using classes and you can call `self.root_pic = ...`

EDIT: As for more images, you would need to create a list:

```
tv._images = []    

for i in range(0, len(db)):
    image = Image.open(db[i]["Pic"])
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image.thumbnail((100, 200), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize
    tv._images.append(image)

    tv.insert('', 'end', image=tv._images[-1], text=db[i]['Name'], values=(db[i]['LName']))
```

Comment: EDIT: Doesnt work on more entries;


_    for i in range(0, len(db)):
        tv._image = Image
        tv._image = Image.open(db[i]["Pic"])
        tv._image.thumbnail((100, 200), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        tv._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tv._image)
        tv.insert('', 'end', image=tv._image, values=(db[i]['Name'], db[i]['LName'])) 
        
        
    tv.pack()_

Comment: Updated the answer for more images.

Comment: The question was about using the `Image` as a value and not as part of the first column `#0`.